# Is it legal to assign heap allocated class object to stack allocated object in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, heap-memory, stack-memory

In C++ we can assign heap allocated object of class to stack allocated object by dereferencing it. It looks like there is no problem and it works as expected even destructor works well, but is it good or bad to write code like this?

```
#include <iostream>

class cls {
public:
    cls(int n) : pInt{new int{n}} {
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";
    }

    int *pInt;

    ~cls() { 
        std::cout << "Destructor\n";

        delete pInt; 
    }
};

int main() {
    cls *hObj = new cls{100};
    cls sObj = *hObj;
}
```

Comment: This program works well? Surprising (because of the reasons pointed out by *Some programmer dude).* Are you sure you don't have a stack dump lying around? Did you check the exit status? Any funny console messages after the second "Destructor" output?

Comment: As an aside, if you simply use a vector instead of manual allocation (which is very often the thing to do) you avoid the dynamic memory administration problems.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica There's no "second" output because only one object is destructed: `sObj`. The OP never deletes `hObj` so its destructor will never run.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right, I was just reading the other comments under your post. Of course there's only 1. In fact, one could use a shallow copy as a RAII sentinel like `cls hObj = *(new cls{100})`, silently sending the original object into oblivion! Not that I would condone that style...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They copying is okay, but note that the compiler-generated copy-constructor will do a *shallow* copy.

That means, the *pointer* is copied, not what it points to. That leads you to have *two* objectd with the exact same `pInt` pointer, pointing to the exact same memory. And you can only `delete` that memory *once*.

This is the reason for [the rules of three, five and zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

---

As for why this program seems to work, it's because you don't `delete hObj`. Only the `sObj` destructor will run, so in the code as currently shown there's only one `delete pInt`.

If you add `delete hObj` before program termination, then both destructors will `delete` the same memory, and you will have *undefined behavior* (and very likely a crash).

Comment: I test it with clang and destructor is called just once. https://godbolt.org/z/4b3Yh4 ; Is it "moved"?

Comment: @LouisGo No, but the OP is never destructing the object pointed to by `hObj`. If you do `delete hObj` then you will attempt to `delete` the memory twice.

Comment: @LuisGo because OPs code misses a `delete hObj;`. bug x bug = looks like it is fine, but it isnt

Comment: @idclev463035818 Indeed, my first thought calling me it `delete` is missing and then I forgot it...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know it's a shallow copy but in some situations you may want to return object by reference not by copying it. If you allocate this in stack and return this bu reference it'll be so bad (returning reference to deleted object) but allocating object in heap and returning reference by dereferencing object is fine. Can we do like this in real programs?

Comment: @Kanony If you allocate an object dynamically (off the heap) and return a reference to it (by dereferencing the pointer) then you have the risk of a *memory leak*. Use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) and the rule of zero, and many problems will go away.

Comment: @Kanony copies of such objects always share the same allocated memory for their member. You can only delete one of the copies. Can you write correct code using such a class? Maybe yes. Will it be a super complicated mess? Certainly yes

Comment: @Kanony -  Your last comment has nothing to do with your question.   But if a reference (or a pointer) to an object out-lives the actual object, and is then used as if that object still exists, then the behaviour is undefined.   Dynamically allocating the object doesn't really fix that, since it is still possible to explicitly destroy a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: @Kanony if `cls` would follow the rule of 3/5/0 then `cls sObj = *hObj;` would be absolutely fine. Don't mix those two issues